# Child Component doesn't re-render after updating the state in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components. UpdateAudio (Parent component) & AudioForm (Child component).

I fetch the data from API in componentDidMount method and update the audio state in UpdateAudio component and pass this audio as props in AudioForm.

Now when I see console.log(this.props.audio) inside the render in AudioForm then I can see new audio value is coming but form doesn't show the data. It's blank.

UpdateAudio.js

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Mutation, Query, graphql } from 'react-apollo';
    import { UpdateAudioQuery, GetAudio } from '../query';
    import { Button, Grid, LinearProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
    import AudioForm from '../components/AudioForm';
    import AudioSaveUpdateButton from '../components/AudioSaveUpdateButton';
    import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo';


    class UpdateAudio extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.site = "5d517862-0630-431c-94b1-bf34de6bfd8b"
            this.state = {
                audio: {
                site: this.site,
                title: '',
                desc: '',
                }
            };
            this.updateCache = this.updateCache.bind(this);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        }

        updateCache = (cache, { data }) => {
            if (data.createAudio.audio.guid) {
                console.log("redirecting...")
                this.props.history.push('/audios')
            }
        }

        handleChange = event => {
            const { name, value } = event.target;

            this.setState(prevState => ({
                audio: {
                ...prevState['audio'],
                [name]: value,
                }
            }));
        };

        componentDidMount = async () => {
            let resp = await this.props.client.query({
                query: GetAudio,
                variables: {site: this.site, guid: this.props.match.params.guid}
            })
            let { data } = resp;
            let audio = data.getAudio;

            this.setState(prevState => ({
                audio: {
                ...prevState['audio'],
                ...audio
                }
            }));
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <AudioForm audio={this.state.audio} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <AudioSaveUpdateButton create={false} audio={this.state.audio} updateCache={this.updateCache} />
                </Fragment>
            )
        }
    }

    UpdateAudio = withRouter(UpdateAudio)

    export default withApollo(UpdateAudio);
```

AudioForm.js

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import { TextField, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';


class AudioForm extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.audio.title, this.props.audio.desc);
    console.log(this.props.audio);

    return (
      <Fragment>
      <form  noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <Grid container spacing={24} alignItems="center" justify="center">
          <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField
              id="audio-title"
              name="title"
              label="Title"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              fullWidth
              defaultValue={this.props.audio.title}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
              required
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField
              id="audio-desc"
              name="desc"
              label="Description"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              fullWidth
              defaultValue={this.props.audio.desc}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
              required
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>      
      </form>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}


export default AudioForm;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: change `defaultValue` to `value`

Comment: Thanks. This was really a silly mistake.